# Swift: how to assign a string array to the text property of an array of UITextFields?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitextfield

If I have 2 string arrays, it'd be fairly simply to assign one to the other in one line of code (w/o having to use a for-loop):

```
var sArray1 = ["A","B","C"]
var sArray2 = sArray1
```

However, I'd like to do something similar with an array of UITextFields, but can't figure it out. I feel like it should look something like this:

```
var sArray1 = ["A","B","C"]
var sArray2 = [textField1, textField2, textField3]
sArray2.text = sArray1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[UITextField]` does not have a `text` property, so you can't use `sArray2.text`.

You can [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) and then `forEach`:

```
zip(sArray2, sArray1).forEach { $0.0.text = $0.1 }
```

Comment: What do you mean that [UITextField] doesn't have a text property? I write things like nameOfTextField.text = "something" all the time. Or are you specifically referring to an array of UITextFields not having that property? It seems like there should be a way to .map the strings to each of the fields in the field array...

Comment: @Kayan `Array` does not have a `text` property, even though its elements do. You could map the textfields to their `text` properties, but then you can't set their texts. Because you want to change the textfield's state, so you should use `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `enumerated()`,

```
let sArray1 = ["A","B","C"]
let sArray2 = [textField1, textField2, textField3]

for (index, element) in sArray2.enumerated() {
    element.text = sArray1[index]
}
print(sArray2)
```

**Output:**

```
[<UITextField: 0x7fd885051200; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'A'; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000024393e0>>, <UITextField: 0x7fd885037a00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'B'; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000024394e0>>, <UITextField: 0x7fd88508f400; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'C'; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000024395e0>>]
```